# textView's in tableViewCell's resizing as they appear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitextview

I have a tableViewController utilizing an NSFetchedResultsController to display data.  The Cell's primarily consist of textView's which resize based on content.  The tableView uses automatically sizing cells.

Everything works fine except that when the tableView is first presented, the cells can be seen resizing horizontally into place.  Subsequently when the tableView is presented the cells are sized correctly.

All other behavior is normal.  When cells are dequeued they are sized normally and do not resize as they appear.

The cell's are subclassed in the normal way and AutoLayout is used.  I have set all the priorities for the content of the textView to 751 in storyboard.

The text is added to the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath with simply cell.textView.text = someText

Just wondering if I need to call tableView.layoutIfNeeded() or any other methods prior to initially displaying the tableViewController.

I am initializing the NSFetchedResultsController in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

After fetching data from your api, you need to call

```
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Okay Next time i will take care @Moritz

Comment: if you call tableView.layoutIfNeeded() before initializing the NSFRC then the tableView delegates will cause a crash with nil NSFRC

Comment: Sorry Please call after data is received and make table reloaddata

Comment: I think the problem might be initializing the NSFRC in viewDidLoad when the frames are not yet set.  I am trying it in viewWillAppear and it seems to be working.

Comment: looks like I spoke too soon.  same problem occurring.